# Looking for a biography of Totapuri Maharaj by Monika Mitra

Tags: advaita, resource, book-recommendation, research

I came across a lady namely, Monika Mitra who had the good fortune of being in close contact of **Totapuri Maharaj** who was a wandering saint. She has written the only account of the saint with the title, **Sree Sree Digambar Baba Popularly Known as Totapuri by Monika Mitra**

I found out that it was published by her husband in 1994 and was digitized in 2008 (per Google Books), but I've been unable to find any digital copy online.

Can anyone else find an online version?

Comment: Where in the world are you located? You can use [this](https://www.worldcat.org/title/609777864) to find out if any library nearby you has the ebook version.